# Windows Phone Push notification

Tags: windows-phone-8, certificate, mpns

Can anyone guide me how to get push notifications from windows phone store. I think I need to install some certificate but not sure how to configure and install the certificate.

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need certificate if you just want to send push notifications to your app (to update tiles, or to show toasts when the app is not running).

On the phone, you need to request a push notification URI from the phone, then send that URi to your server and the server can then use it to send the notifications back to the phone.

Check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402558%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

I think that you need a certificate only if you want the communication to occur over https instead of http, and to send more than 500 notifications per day per phone.

Comment: I need to send the push notification over https and more than 500..so how can i add certificate for this